# Why does this code return junk values along with the right output?

Tags: c, output, cs50, caesar-cipher

I was writing a program that would act as a Caesar Cipher encoder. However for only single letter inputs, the encrypted charecter is sometimes returned along with junk charecters.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>

int check_validity(string);
int atoi(string);
void cipher(int ,string, int);


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
     if(argc == 2)
     {
          check_validity(argv[1]);
          if(check_validity(argv[1]) == 0)
          {
               string c = get_string("plaintext: ");
               int key = atoi(argv[1]);
               int cipher_key = key%26;
               int length = strlen(c);
               cipher(cipher_key, c, length);
               return 0;
          }
          else printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
      }
      else 
      {
          printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
          return 1;
      }
}

int check_validity(string w)
{
    int j = 0;
    string a;
    for(int i = 0;w[i] != 0; i++)
    {
         if(w[i]<47 || w[i]>58)
         {
              j++;
         }
     }
     return j;

}

int atoi(string w)
{
     int number = 0;
     for (int i = 0; w[i] != 0; i++)
     {
         number = number*10 + (w[i]-'0');
     }
     return number;
 }

 void cipher(int x, string q, int l)
 {
     char b[l];
     for(int i=0; q[i] != 0; i++)
     {
          if(q[i]>64 && q[i]<91)
          {
               if(q[i]<91-x)
               {
                    b[i] = q[i] + x;
               }
           else b[i] = q[i] + x - 26;
           }
           else if(q[i]>96 && q[i]<123)
           {
                if(q[i]<123-x)
                {
                    b[i] = q[i] + x;
                }
                else b[i] = q[i] + x - 26;
           }
           else b[i] = q[i];
           }
           printf("ciphertext: %s\n",b);
}
```

Input:
./caesar 1
plaintext: a

Output 1:
b

Output 2:
b>

Output 3:
b2

Changing the key lends the same problem. However this seems to be absent for all other string of letters entered.

Comment: You should not use magic numbers: `if(w[i]<47 || w[i]>58)` => `if(w[i]<'0'-1 || w[i]>'9'+1)`. As a side effect you can see that this does not properly detect digits because you are off by 1. Also you could just use `isdigit` function from `ctype.h`.

Comment: Strings in C consist of a byte for each character, *plus a zero byte to mark the end of the string*. The `b[]` array in your `cipher()` function is one byte too small, and you forgot to terminate the output string.

Comment: The first call to `check_validity` is useless.

Comment: @Gerhardh I'm simply using check_validity to check if the user enters a number as the cipher key instead of other charecters. Since I am getting an output with the correctly encoded charecter, I assumed that that wasn't causing the output of additional junk charecters.

Comment: That is not causing this specific error but it is still wrong. With your magic numbers you rely on using ASCII encoding. But then `48=='0'` and `57=='9'`. Your checks are a bit off and accept `'0'-1` and `'9'+1` as valid input as well, which is probably not what you want. If you mean the character `'0'` etc., use it in your code instead of a number that depends on the encoding of your character set. That makes it much more readable.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks Gerhardh.

Comment: @r3mainer Terminating the output string solved the error. Thanks r3mainer.

Comment: the function: `atoi()` is in conflict with the `atoi()` exposed in the header file: `stdlib.h`.   suggest changing your `atoi()` function name to something like: `myAtoi()`

Comment: OT: the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`

Comment: OT: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");`  error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Suggest:  `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s caesarKey\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: regarding: `check_validity(argv[1]);
          if(check_validity(argv[1]) == 0)`  Why call `check_validity()` twice in a row?  The first call is ignoring the returned value and nothing will have changed for the second call.  Suggest removing the first call

Comment: OT: for ease of understanding and readability: 1) use meaningful variable names.  single char names are meaningless, except as indexes.